# how to take the date only from a MySQL database datestamp in angular Js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, laravel

i need to use the created_at from the JSON given here and using angular , i want just the date to print. How to do that?

```
files":{"65":[{"id":5,"ticket_id":65,"file_name":"1434545168_South Park s10e10 - Miss Teacher Bangs a Boy _ 480p UNCENSORED x264 NIT158.srt","file_size":"30893","file_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/levigo\/storage\/app\/1434545168_South Park s10e10 - Miss Teacher Bangs a Boy _ 480p UNCENSORED x264 NIT158.srt","**created_at":"2015-06-17 18:16:08"**},{"id":6,"ticket_id":65,"file_name":"1434545196_6croMg5xi.png","file_size":"65412","file_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/levigo\/storage\/app\/1434545196_6croMg5xi.png","created_at":"2015-06-17 18:16:36"},{"id":7,"ticket_id":65,"file_name":"1434545214_6croMg5xi.png","file_size":"65412","file_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/levigo\/storage\/app\/1434545214_6croMg5xi.png","created_at":"2015-06-17 18:16:54"}],"66":[]}
```

**I have done this by making my filter but it is not working and given wrong ouput**

```
myApp.filter('format', function () {
      return function (item) {
           var t = item.split(/[- :]/);
       var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
       var time=d.getTime();                 
               return time;
      };
    });
```

Comment: what output does the filter give then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want you could keep it extremely simple:

```
app.filter('format', function () {
      return function (item) {
        return new Date(item);
      };
    });
```

then in your view:

```
{{modelVariable | format | date}}
```

This will show `Jun 17, 2015`

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/owgGuObABdEpSCkp5iC3?p=preview)

---

Alternatively skip the filter altogether:

```
$scope.theDate = new Date(2015-06-17 18:16:08);

{{theDate | date}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return function (item) {
           var t = item // this nothing but created date "2015-06-17 18:16:08"
       var d = new Date(t); // i.e var d = new Date("2015-06-17 18:16:08")
       var time= d.getTime(); 
       time = d.getDate()+"-"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+d.getFullYear();     
               return time; // return milliseconds
      };
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/j2crooys/1/)